# Какая сделать явную специализацию для функции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```cpp
template <typename T>
T foo(const T* arr, int n) { T b=0; return b;}

template <> const char* foo<const char*>(const char** ch, int n){}
```

Какая сделать явную специализацию для функции foo оставив `const T* arr`??

Comment: В смысле оставив T? Это же специализация. Если бы у вас был шаблон с двумя параметрами, то можно было бы его частично специализировать, а так нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое вас не устроит?

```
template <>
const char* foo<const char*>(const char * const * ch, int n)
{
    return *ch;

}
```